# best way to migrate PHP Pages into GWT

Tags: php, gwt, uibinder

I'm looking for a good strategy to migrate a PHP website into GWT front-end based site.

i'm intending to use UIBinder to build the UI for new GWT Pages. The PHP pages have a set of resources (images, js files and css files).

what is a good strategy to follow to convert HTML/CSS UI into UIBinder GWT ?

thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494385/how-to-mix-html-and-gwt-widgets-using-uibinder

Answer (score 0):

This question's kind of vague. Anything that was a DIV would become a "Panel" of some sort, FlowPanel, HTMLPanel, etc. The CSS can live right alongside the markup in GWT in a UIBinder ui.xml file, inside a  block. Not sure what you mean exactly by this question.

Comment: Not *every* div has to become a `Panel`, just the ones that will contain other widgets. An `HTMLPanel` can contain regular `<div>`s, `<span>`s, etc.

Comment: i mean if some body gave you a PHP web site with UI stuff and asked you to convert the UI into GWT ,what would you think about? what procedure would you examine to do this migration? i'm not sure what other info i should include in question? I mean in PHP pages there is a bunch of divs ,tables ect and i need a good way to migrate all this stuff into GWT widgets.

Comment: suppose you were asked to migrate this page [link](http://www.cloudally.com/index.php) into GWT. what would your strategy be? would you convert each div into a GWT Panel? ,what page elements would you be interested into making a GWT widget and what parts would you leave as plain html? -thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had a hard time moving a php website over to GWT myself.

Here is what I learned.
Firstly I learned that I didn't really want to move everything over to GWT.
There is a lot that is hard to move into a GWT project IE bootstrap.

Instead I would recommend using jsp instead for most pages. Jsp is a lot like php and will work with your existing GWT project. Here are a couple links that kind of look at that.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code
http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html

Gwt is best at one page intensive apps and it might be easiest to make everything jsp then move individual pages into GWT.

Anyway here is what I think the easiest way to go about it.
1. Copy your php site into the war folder of your gwt project
2. Rename all of the php files to jsp
   If you are using linux here is a command to do that

```
rename 's/\.php$/\.jsp/' *.php
```

3. Go through and change all

```
<?php to <% and ?> to %>
```

My preference is to actually change them to

```
<!--TODO% and %-->
```

If you are using linux here is a command to do that

```
grep -rl "<?php" *.jsp  | xargs sed -i 's|<?php|<!--TODO%|g'  
grep -rl "?>" *.jsp  | xargs sed -i 's|?>|%-->|g'
```

4. Go through and change all of those php sections to java
5. Go through and convert whatever pages you want to gwt
6. Update your web.xml file

Cheers, hope this helps