# How to mix HTML and GWT widgets using UIBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

We have an existing UI built with UIBinder whose ui.xml file contains the following hierarchy:

```
<ui:UiBinder>
<div>
Multiple <span> or <a> separated by verbatim HTML (like | separators).
```

I need to replace one of the anchors with a listbox.

Is there a way to make this transition without replacing the div with an HTMLPanel and changing all the anchors to something else?

If I try to stick a gwt:ValueListBox or gwt:ListBox in there, I get an error message that I cannot mix the two. I also cannot have multiple children (such as a div and an HTMLPanel) under the UIBinder.

If my only option is to convert everything to widgets, what are the appropriate conversions for  and  items?

Comment: why don't you add an HTMLPanel to the binder and then put your div and the rest of your HTML inside ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In UIBinder, `HTMLPanel` can contain HTML elements and GWT widgets, but HTML elements can only contain other HTML elements.

Just replace top-level `div` with `HTMLPanel`, then replace only a specific `<a>` anchor with `gwt:ListBox`.

Comment: …and of course, in your Java code, you'd probably have to `extends Composite` and `initWidget` rather than `extends Widget` and `setElement`.

Comment: from HTMLPanel javadoc: "A panel that contains HTML, and which can attach child widgets to identified elements within that HTML." - this suggest that HTML elements can in fact contain Widgets

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
<gwt:HTMLPanel>
    <div align="center">
        <gwt:VerticalPanel res:styleName="style.background">
```